# Well Defined Maps

Tags: differential-geometry

How do you show the existence and well definedness of a map between two smooth manifolds?

For instance, if we have some submanifold $\Sigma$ with dimesion $n$ of $M\times N$, where both $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with dimension $n$, then we have the projection map defined by $\pi_M :M\times N \rightarrow M$ and $\pi_N :M\times N \rightarrow N$ and the inclusion map $i_{\Sigma}:\Sigma\rightarrow M\times N.$ If $\pi_M\circ i_{\Sigma}$ is bijective, then how can we show that there exists a smooth well defined map $\Psi:M\rightarrow N$, such that $\Sigma = \{(p,\Psi(p))\in M\times N; p\in M\}.$

(Further note, there exists some $n$-form $\omega$ on $M$, such that $i_{\Sigma}^*\pi_M^*\omega$ is nowhere zero).

Drawing the map, it seems obvious that there should be a map $\Psi$, but not sure how to show it is well defined.

This is a typical problem in my book, and I am struggling to show formally why this is true. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: The wordnig is slightly redundant: If a map is not well-defined, it doesn't really exist to begin with.

Comment: I have edited the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the inverse of $\pi_M\circ i$. The following diagram is commutative.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Sigma @>{i}>> U\times N\\
@A{f}AA @VV{\pi_M}V \\
U @<{id}<<   U 
\end{CD}
But $f$ is a bijection and $\dim M = \dim\Sigma $, so $U = M$ (edit: This is is wrong, and it is the crucial point. Is $\pi_M\circ i$ a bijection into the image of $i$, or into $M$? The latter would solve the problem.). Then, the diagram can be extended to
\begin{CD}
\Sigma @>{i}>> M\times N@>{\pi_N}>>N\\
@A{f}AA @VV{\pi_M}V \\
M @<{id}<<   M 
\end{CD}
Choosing $\Psi = \pi_N\circ i\circ f$ does the trick.

Being well defined means that $\Psi(p)$ is actually a point of $N$. It clearly is.